# Do these look like good PVC exhaust and intake termination ends for a new tankless gas heater?

Tags: pvc, exhaust-vent, tankless

I just had a new tankless gas water heater installed, and it seems to be working well. But looking around here, other sites, and my own HVAC system, the terminating ends seem to come out further from the wall.

As per the photo, the down curved 2in pipe is the intake, and the short straight one is the exhaust. This seems like a good way?

Thank you.

[image: terminating ends]

Comment: what problem are you seeing?

Comment: No problem, just that by looking around here, other sites, and my own old HVAC system, the terminating ends seem to come out further from the wall, and both curve.

Answer (score 1):

I look at that picture ans see loose electrical cables, and damaged lagging on the water pipe,
Is see a messy glue job on the end of the intake, (but some paint will hide that)

I finally see that the penetration through the sheet-metal siding has not been sealed. same as the water pipe...

It doesn't look like a big problem.

Comment: Thank you. That is a coaxial cable, and AC refrigerant line. So I just need to possibly paint the PVC, and seal the pipes within the siding with some gray Paintable Advanced Sealant Caulk?

Comment: Agreed that the unsealed siding gaps seem to be a much greater issue than the pipe itself. Installing a finish box (like the one around the pipe to the left) would have made for a much more professional job and would have made it much easier to seal out water.

Comment: Makes sense. To be fair to the plumber who did the heater, the box was installed by the siding people some time ago. Alright, so I add some QUAD Advanced Formula 10 fl. oz. Gray #517 Window Door and Siding Sealant from home depot, and all else looks good?